# Fazer com que width da <ul> fique igual a width de uma imagem que esta dentro de um <li> da <ul>

Tags: css, html5, imagem

Tenho uma ul, dentro dela tem 3 li, dentro de uma dessas li tem uma imagem, eu gostaria de saber se tem um método via css para fazer com que a width da ul fique igual a width da imagem. (sem alterar a width da imagem)
Eu quero fazer isso pois os textos acabam ficando com a width maior do que a da imagem e não posso alterar o tamanho da imagem

```
<ul>
    <li><p>Texto texto texto</p></li>
    <li><img src="qualquer-img.png" alt="qualquer img"></li>
    <li><p>Texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto</p></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Eu acredito que esse deveria ser o comportamento padrão da ul. Você pode incluir o CSS que você utiliza?

Comment: o problema é que os textos acabam ficando maiores que a imagem, e ainda não adicionei css nesta parte do código.

Comment: Talvez usar width e height definido?

Comment: Como disse na pergunta não posso alterar o tamanho da imagem e irei ter varias listas assim e gostaria de uma solução para todas

Answer (score 0):

Coloque float: left na sua ul, assim o tamanho da ul se adequará a seu conteúdo.

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li><p>Texto texto texto</p></li>
    <li><img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/modern-abstract-background_1048-1003.jpg" alt="qualquer img"></li>
    <li><p>Texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto</p></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul {  
  float: left;
}

ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

Comment: Não era exatamente isso que eu gostaria, eu preciso que a ul fique com a width da img e não o contrário.

Comment: @DanielCastro alterei o css, veja se te atende. Fiz no JSBin, segue o link: https://jsbin.com/sobeqexomu/edit?html,css,output